# Python raw_input won't prompt

Tags: python, input

The input wont prompt when I run the program. How do I fix this?

```
import sys
def main():

    # Initialize list and determine length
    string_list = raw_input("Enter your strings to be sorted: ").split(' ')
    string_list.sort()
    length = len(string_list)

    # If there are more than one strings to sort, print the list
    # Otherwise break
    if length > 1: 
        print(string_list)
    elif length < 0:
        print("Enter more than one string to sort")
        return sys.exit()
```

Comment: Did you call the func i.e. `main()`?

Comment: How would I do that? I am just starting with python

Comment: next issue, `elif length < 0`, you expect strings to have a negative length?! I guess you mean `< 1` and don't `return sys.exit()` just call `sys.exit()`

Comment: Python doesn't automatically call `main` functions like some other languages.  Instead, Python will run all the code at the top level of the file (that is, not encapsulated in a function.)  What most people do is take advantage of the [scope checking](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) that python offers to make sure their code is only run when called directly

Comment: Yes I meant < 1 typo. ok will just call exit

Comment: Note: `return sys.exit()` is totally unecessary. But anyway, as others have stated, if this is *exactly* the code you are running, nothing will happen except a function will get defined.

Comment: @ncotton there's no need to call `sys.exit()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard idiom is useful here:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call your function.  As it is it is not executing anything but closing immediately.  In this case you can call your execute it with `main()`:

```
import sys
def main():

    # Initialize list and determine length
    string_list = raw_input("Enter your strings to be sorted: ").split(' ')
    string_list.sort()
    length = len(string_list)

    # If there are more than one strings to sort, print the list
    # Otherwise break
    if length > 1: 
        print(string_list)
    elif length < 0:
        print("Enter more than one string to sort")
        return sys.exit()
main()
```

When you create a function you create code that is never executed unless it is called.  This is useful when creating modules for example because it does not execute it immediately.

It seems you are used to another language because unlike some (C++/C/Java) you do not need to use a function for structural purposes but rather to not call code or clarity.

Also Python automatically stops executing.  Unlike (once again C/C++) you do not need to return anything.

In the case of:

```
if length > 1: 
    print(string_list)
elif length < 0:
    print("Enter more than one string to sort")
    return sys.exit()
```

Rather than printing (which might be considered bad practice) you can return the string:

```
if length > 1: 
    return string_list
elif length < 0:
    return "Enter more than one string to sort"
```

Now to get it to print you can use `print(main())`

You should also ensure to end in either a plain `if` or an `else` statement.  Ending with a `elif` can return strange errors.

If you still need those two loops you could add an `else` statement at the end and using the `pass` function that does nothing:

```
if length > 1: 
    return string_list
elif length < 0:
    return "Enter more than one string to sort"
else: pass
```

---

Once you move on to modules, you may want to execute code that  can be executed and is also a module.  This is where the other answer helps.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This specifies if the name of the script (try running `print(__name__)` in a script) is the main file (i.e. it's not getting called by another script) then *only then* will it execute by itself.  Otherwise if imported `main()` will not run.

Comment: @ncotton  No problem.  :-)

Comment: `if length > 1` / `elif length < 0` makes no sense. What about 1-character strings? Do you think there are strings with negative length? The correct idiom is `if string` / `else`.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson  The values might be negative am I wrong then?

Comment: Length cannot be negative.